# Randomly switch between two PHP functions

Tags: php, random

I have 2 PHP functions on a webpage. I would like to run one of those 2 functions randomly. I know how to do it with `div`s or HTML using PHP, but not how to run a PHP function randomly. I want to use PHP and not Javascript.

Here are my 2 functions:

```
<?php get_template_part('module_sidebar_1'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('module_sidebar_2'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also have mixed (numeric + non-numeric) template names,
Create an array with all template names like,

```
$templates = ['module_sidebar_1','module_sidebar_2','module_sidebar_non_numeric'];
```

and call random template file by

```
<?php get_template_part($templates[array_rand($templates)])?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`mt_rand();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) to generate the number at the end.

```
<?php get_template_part('module_sidebar_'.mt_rand(1,2)); ?>
```

This will randomly pick one of your two templates.

To use words instead of numbers, just use an array. Create an array of template names then use mt_rand for the array key.

```
$array = ['module_sidebar_sondage', 'module_sid‌​ebar_bon_plan'];
get_template_part($array[mt_rand(0,1)]);
```

Comment: thanks, nice way to do it,  but does it only works with numeric values ? I mean I used 1 and 2 for an example, but the real names are module_sidebar_sondage & module_sidebar_bon_plan. Will it works with <?php get_template_part('module_sidebar_'.mt_rand("module_sidebar_sondage","module_sidebar_bon_plan")); ?>

Comment: @mmdwc I've updated my answer to show you how to use words instead of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
$random = rand(0,1);
if ($random == 0){
    get_template_part('module_sidebar_1');
}
else{
    get_template_part('module_sidebar_2');
}
```

Comment: thanks @Pavel Němec I just added a $ before random on line 2 and it works perfectly, thanks a lot !